# WebView2 proxy C++

Tags: c++, webview2

I found [this](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Feedback/issues/193) thread on GitHub, but seems that the code is not C++:

```
WebView2 _webView2 = new WebView2();

CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions options = new CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions();

// Set a proxy pac for the browser   
//      options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-pac-url=http://myproxy.com/my.pac";

// Set the proxy for the browser
options.AdditionalBrowserArguments = "--proxy-server=\"foopy:99\"";

// Create the environment manually
CoreWebView2Environment env = await CoreWebView2Environment.CreateAsync(null, null, options);
await _webView2 .EnsureCoreWebView2Async(env);
```

So the only what am I asking for is to provide the solution for setting up a proxy for WebView2 via C++.

---

I have `ICoreWebView2` interface, but it doesn’t have `EnsureCoreWebView2Async` method. In another hand, I have `CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` class.

Comment: Have you read: https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/microsoft-edge/webview2/gettingstarted/win32 ? It shows the basic use for C++

Comment: @PoulBak, obviously I’ve read, but seems another article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2environmentoptions?view=webview2-1.0.664.37 may help me

Comment: As a side note, if you have code or documentation for another language, you might need to check if desired methods have been added to a derived interface (usually same name but with _2, _3... at the end)

Answer (score 2):

```
auto opt = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();

opt->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--proxy-server=\"SERVER\"");

CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(nullptr, nullptr, opt.Get(), Microsoft::WRL::Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
[hwnd](HRESULT result, ICoreWebView2Environment* env) -> HRESULT {

...

}).Get());
```

Instead of `SERVER` put ip address or something else.

---

I tested, it works, but seems there is a bug (or feature): you can’t create two or more webviews with different run-arguments.

Comment: All `WebView2` instances share the same native browser. Setting the Environment on second instance is simply ignored.

Answer (score 2):

To those looking to specify webview environment options and cannot find `CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions` in C++ similar to what is available in .Net. Visit [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/icorewebview2environmentoptions) page for ICoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions and you should find this line:

`A default implementation is provided in WebView2EnvironmentOptions.h`

Include WebView2EnvironmentOptions.h and create CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions as below

```
#include <WebView2EnvironmentOptions.h>

auto options = Microsoft::WRL::Make<CoreWebView2EnvironmentOptions>();
// Use options however you want. I simply added an argument to autoplay videos.
options->put_AdditionalBrowserArguments(L"--autoplay-policy=no-user-gesture-required");

HRESULT hr = CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentWithOptions(
        subFolder, m_userDataFolder.c_str(), options.Get(),
        Callback<ICoreWebView2CreateCoreWebView2EnvironmentCompletedHandler>(
            this, &AppWindow::OnCreateEnvironmentCompleted)
            .Get());
```